# What happens to a pending transaction after it posts?

Tags: yodlee

Does the transaction id change (ie a new transaction is created), or does just the status code change from pending to posted the next time you pull a users transactions using yodlee?

Answer (score 0):

Yodlee deletes the pending transaction and files it as a new transaction with status as posted into Yodlee's DB.

In detail:
@Jacopo When Yodlee scrapes data from the Bank website, Yodlee deletes the pending transactions from its DB assuming that the latest resonse(which it scraped from bank website) will have either those as Pending or few of them might have converted into Posted. Yodlee doesn't maintain any relationship between Pending and Posted transactions.

For your better understanding, I am providing you an example.
Say Yodlee received 3 pending transactions in last refresh, it filed the same in the DB. Now, when you'll make an API call to pull Pending transactions you'll receive those 3 transactions. But in next refresh(i.e. when Yodlee scrapes data from bank website) Yodlee receives only 1 as Pending transaction from Bank website,then it will first delete all those 3 Pending transactions from its DB(which was filed in last refresh) assuming those would have converted to Posted and file this 1 pending transaction in the DB. Now when you'll pull Pending transactions from Yodlee you'll receive only 1 Pending transaction. And if the rest of transactions would have converted into Posted then you'll receive those when you pull Posted transactions.

Comment: I should have phrased my question a bit differently. If i refresh my user transactions every 24 hours, what is the correct way to know what happened to pending transactions that i got in the last refresh. Which ones turned from pending to posted, which ones changed amounts(ie the pending amount changed from 1 dollars to 2 for the same trasnaction), which where canceled, which were just temporary auths?

Comment: @Jacopo - Please read the answer I have edited the same. Hope this helps.